# Makefile executes the command only once

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am using the Makefile of MinGW (Windows 8.1, GCC 7.3.0) to build a medium-sized project automatically detecting all source files under the folder `src` and compiling all object files into the `obj` folder, but unfortunately it is only executing the command over the first detected file and stops there.

This is the first time I write a Makefile script for anything beyond one source file and maybe I am getting some rule wrongly. Thanks in advance!

```
CC   := gcc

SRC  := src
OBJ  := obj

MAIN := main
PACK := libbundle

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c,$(OBJ)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
CFLAGS := -I$(SRC)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# build:
#   ar rcs $(PACK).a $(OBJECTS)
#   $(CC) -shared -o $(PACK).so $(OBJECTS)
#   $(CC) -o $(MAIN).c $(PACK).so
```

Output:

`gcc -Isrc -c src/firstsource.c -o obj/firstsource.o`

...and stops there!

Comment: You are missing the link step in your makefile. enable the `build`.

Comment: By default, `make` makes the first target in the makefile.  In your case, the first target is `firstsource.o` — so it did exactly what it was told to do.  If you want it to do more, tell it you want all the objects with a rule such as `all: ${OBJECTS}` before the current first target.  Or have the `all` target depend on the program, or shared library, that you're trying to create, and then that program or library depends on the object files, and the object files depend on the source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem - rule with multiple targets

Your rule

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

has *multiple targets*. I don't believe this is appropriate here. See discussion [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets) of where rules with multiple targets are useful.

Also, this rule specifies multiple prerequisites - but `$<` represents *only the first prerequisite*. You can use `$+` to capture *all* prerequisites - but then you lose the ability to use the `-o` option. See below if you want to use multiple prerequisites.

#### What `$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)` means in detail

Suppose, for example, that your `src/` directory contains `firstsource.c` and `secondsource.c`. Then your variables become

```
$(SOURCES) -> src/firstsource.c src/secondsource.c
$(OBJECTS) -> obj/firstsource.o obj/secondsource.o
```

(Actually - and somewhat non-intuitively - firstsource will be placed *after* secondsource, but let's ignore that for simplicity's sake.)

So the rule

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

is equivalent to

```
obj/firstsource.o obj/secondsource.o: src/firstsource.c src/secondsource.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This rule, in turn, is equivalent to *two rules* (since it has multiple targets) - each with the same prerequisites:

```
obj/firstsource.o: src/firstsource.c src/secondsource.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

obj/secondsource.o: src/firstsource.c src/secondsource.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Can you see the problem here?

Since `$<` represents *only the first prerequisite*, the recipe for the first rule becomes

```
    gcc -Isrc -c src/firstsource.c -o obj/firstsource.o
```

which is fine for the first rule, but for the second rule it won't work

```
    gcc -Isrc -c src/firstsource.c -o obj/secondsource.o
```

because you are using the wrong input file.

By the way ... You mentioned that

> unfortunately it [i.e. `make`] is only executing the command over the first detected file and stops there.

This is because - when you invoke `make` without any arguments - it calls the first rule in the file and no more.

#### Option 1: Use multiple rules

What is more suitable here are multiple rules - each with only a *single target*. So try replacing the above with the following.

```
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

compile-only: $(OBJECTS)
```

You could invoke `make` on this modified Makefile as

```
make -B compile-only
```

#### Option 2: Single target with multiple prerequisites

If you have multiple prerequisites in your target, you can refer to them in your recipe using the special variable `$+`. However, you can not use the `-o` option in this case - so will not be able to specify the output directory for the object files. (To work around this, you could `cd` to the `obj` directory before compiling - but then you will need to tweak the `SOURCES` variable.)

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Isrc
SRC := src

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)

myobjs: $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $+
```

This will place all the object files in the top-level directory. As mentioned, you can tweak `SOURCES` and `cd` the `obj` directory if you must place the object files in a separate directory.

#### Aside - pre-defined recipes for pattern rules

I understand the rationale in placing the build output in a separate directory as you have done, but - *if* you were willing to place the build output in the same directory as the source files - you could simplify your Makefile using `make`'s [predefined pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples).

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

compile: $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: This `OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.c=.o)` will put the objects in the SRC directory.

Comment: @shawnhcorey: I know that - and I make that caveat in my answer. I was merely suggesting one way in which the user could simplify the Makefile _if_ they were willing to accept that caveat.

Comment: Jeez! The **Option 1** worked as a charm, but I did not understand really well what is happening there. I dunno if I got it right so let me try to explain what I understood from this. 1. First you wrote a rule that can be eventually executed whenever the "target" involved is called? 2. Then you write a rule (shell command, `compile-only`) that points out to the prerequisite list of `OBJECTS` 3. The rule then iterates over the object files list applying the previously stated rule (for the object files in `obj` folder) Is my logic correct? And what is the `-B` flag in the Makefile call means?

Comment: @phtdacosta: The `-B` option simply instructs `make` to build the target even if it has already been built. Regarding your other points ... It is difficult to respond to them in a comment. I will try to update my answer over the coming days if time permits.

Comment: @phtdacosta: I have updated the answer with more detail on what `$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)` actually means (and why it doesn't work as you expect). Hopefully that helps to clarify rather than confuse!
Regarding 'Option 1' ... Your logic is essentially correct yes.These [few paragraphs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-Make-Works) from the make manual might help also.

Comment: You smashed it! I've been studying Makefile the last couple of days and that becomes pretty intuitive when you got these kind of gotchas, but I still consulted your answers some times. Thanks for your time @DavidCollins

Answer (score 0):

You should use [standard targets](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html) in your Makefile, the most important one being "all". And it should be the first target in the Makefile so that `make` and `make all` do the same thing.

```
all: $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: The OP's Makefile indicates that they have a separate target for the linking stage - so using a default target for the compilation stage probably won't work in this case.
Also, the example you have shown won't resolve the OP's primary problem - that the target `$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)` is not doing what they expect.

Answer (score 0):

With `$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)` you are telling make that each file in `$(OBJECTS)` depends on every file in `$(SOURCES)` and will execute the commands below as any of the objects fails the test of being newer than any of the sources.  The command will be executed only once and stop.

What you need is to specify that each object file depends on its correspondient source file.  As I see you are using GMAKE syntax, I'll show you the GNU make syntax for such a rule:

```
$(OBJECTS): obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

this is as if you had a rule for each `.o` file that says how to compile it from its proper source file.

you will also need to say which files are your default targets, with something like:

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJECTS)
clean:
     $(RM) $(TOCLEAN)
```

put that rule the first one, so it will be selected by default.

This will make `all` your default target.  It will explode into all your object files, and for each object you have a rule that says how to compile it (not neccessary, as gnu make already know how to compile a C program, but repeating it here doesn't hurt)

your final `Makefile` is:

```
CC   := gcc

SRC  := src
OBJ  := obj

MAIN := main
PACK := libbundle
CFLAGS := -I$(SRC)
PICFLAGS := -fPIC


SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
TOCLEAN += $(OBJECTS)
PICOBJECTS := $(patsubst $(OBJ)/%.o, $(OBJ)/%.pic, $(OBJECTS))
TOCLEAN += $(PICOBJECTS)

.PHONY: all

.SUFFIXES: .c .o .pic

all: $(PACK).a $(MAIN)
clean:
    $(RM) $(TOCLEAN)

$(MAIN): $(MAIN).o $(PACK).so
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $+
TOCLEAN += $(MAIN)

$(PACK).a: $(OBJECTS)
    ar r $(PACK).a $(OBJECTS)
TOCLEAN += $(PACK).a

$(PACK).so: $(PICOBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $(PACK).so $(PICOBJECTS)
TOCLEAN += $(PACK).so

# this to create a normal .o file in $(OBJ) directory.
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# this to create a PIC (Position Independent Code) .pic object in $(OBJ) directory.
# (REQUIRED FOR .so SHARED OBJECT)
$(PICOBJECTS): $(OBJ)/%.pic: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(PICFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```